# RecyclerView showing one row instead of multiple

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm rather new to Android development and I'm following along this tutorial here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18VcnYN5_LM My problem is that when compiling, I'm only getting one row instead of five rows. I've watched the video three times now, and I don't get what I'm missing. Can you help me spot the problem? Thank you for your help!

I've include MainActivity.java, myAdapter.java, my_row.xml, strings.xml, and activity_main.xml. Below is a screenshot of where I'm only seeing one row instead of five.

[Screenshot of app showing 1 row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfHbZ.png)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String s1[], s2[];

    int images[] = {
        R.drawable.c,
        R.drawable.csharp,
        R.drawable.java,
        R.drawable.php,
        R.drawable.swift
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.programming_languages);
        s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);

        myAdapter myAdapter = new myAdapter(this, s1, s2, images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

my_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/programming_language_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/programming_language_text" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

myAdapter.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    String data1[], data2[];
    int images[];
    Context context;

    public myAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], int img[]) {
        context = ct;
        data1 = s1;
        data2 = s2;
        images = img;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.myText1.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.myText2.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data1.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myText1, myText2;
        ImageView myImage;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.programming_language_text);
            myText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
            myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        }
    }

}
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">RecyclerViewTest</string>

    <string-array name="programming_languages">
        <item>C++</item>
        <item>C#</item>
        <item>Java</item>
        <item>PHP</item>
        <item>Swift</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="description">
        <item>Lorem ipsum C++</item>
        <item>Lorem ipsum C#</item>
        <item>Lorem ipsum Java</item>
        <item>Lorem ipsum PHP</item>
        <item>Lorem ipsum Swift</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="601dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: make sure that your s1 array length is more than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="601dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

in activity_main.xml to

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Edit after comment: 
Please change **height** of `ConstraintLayout` in your my_row.xml.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Thank you @Massab! I was able to scroll up and see the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th rows, but I'm not sure why there's spacing. Here's what it looks like now - https://i.ibb.co/kh1TFDz/Screen-Shot-2020-03-12-at-12-37-07-PM.png